# Android: Group notification in status bar but not in notifications list

Tags: android, notifications

Does anyone know if there is a way to group a notification in the status bar but not in the list of notifications?

I want to show only one icon in the status bar but when the user drags down the "notifications list" it should be several notifications with different intents.

As I understood there is only possible to either group both notifications on both places or to create several notifications which will cause several notifications in the status bar.
Is this the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As I undestood there is only possible to either group both notifications on both places or to create several
>   notifications which will cause several notifications in the status bar. Is this the case?

Yes, but you can create as complex of a [custom](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView) [`Notification`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) view as you want, via the `contentView` field on `Notification`. This is a [`RemoteViews`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html), better known as the what you use for rendering a home screen app widget. So, while there can only be one entry in the notification drawer for you, you can have it have several buttons each firing a separate `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Thanks. I already have a custom contentview for my notification, no when I know the limitation I can figure out how to use the content view to present the notifications the way I want.

Comment: @CommonsWare please give example.Now a days it is very useful

Comment: @Rajat: See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#custom). See also [this example app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.4/Notifications/CustomView).