# facebook like - Android Notification (Not using Notification Builder). How can i achieve that?

Tags: android, notifications

I have been doing a lot of research and trials & errors on notification, using Platform 2.2.. Here's the thing, the status bar number is really getting on my nerve..

When i use a single ID, obviously, it would update the older notification, my application doesn't suit that.

When i use different ID (incrementing a Shared Pref int), it would do what i want, stacking unread notifications, not updating the older one. The problem is the notification number/icon in the status bar.. it make new notification icon in the status bar for every notification.. that's ugly.. how can i make the it only 1 icon, and the number is the number of unread notifications.

I have had searched well enough i think, but can't find a definitive answer...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752763/android-group-notification-in-status-bar-but-not-in-notifications-list) pertains to what you are asking for.

You could create a custom notification view that lists the new messages and each message list item will fire it's own pending intent.  That way, you have one notification showing all the new messages.

Answer (score 0):

I don' t know how you build your notifications, but i suppose you are giving the drawable' s id to the Notification class' constructor as a parameter. If you do this, you can' t control the status bar icons. Try skipping this and use a customized xml for your notifications, and give the icon within this xml. So that Android will not know if your notification has an icon and can' t place it on the status bar. [Here](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/02/20/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-on-android/)  is an example.