# Increment push notification number

Tags: android, parse-platform

I use Parse.com for my android app's backend. I also send some push notifications to users using Parse Cloud Code. When I send multiple pushes to a user, he gets multiple push notifications, how do I increment the number in the notification in the phone rather than making multiple notifications appear?

Comment: kindly check your manifest, i faced the same thing as you, just check if any redundant parse receiver code is present in manifest

Comment: read answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3756438/1168654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish a Notification, you specify an ID, like so (the number 123 in this example):

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mActivity, NotificationPublisher.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 123);
```

If you want to send a new notification, and replace this one, make sure you set the *same* ID when you send a new notification (which will replace the existing notification with your new content)

Comment: Can you provide more information? I am new to notification, can you help me with what I need to look for in google for the solution?

Comment: Did you try Googling "Android Notifications".  I found this document very helpful: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html